# Regular expression one liner that knows if a substitute variable is filled

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to detect and if a match variable (inside a regular expression) is filled, so that it can be used inside the one liner. If the variable is filled, I want to prepend or postpend text that I wouldn't otherwise:

In Bash the syntax for if a variable exists is:

```
$ FOO="asdf"
$ echo ${FOO:+'hello'$FOO}
helloasdf
```

So if I write a regular expression search and replace:

```
$ echo "Foo big Bar" | sed -e 's/Foo(.*?)(Bar)/Hello${1}$2/'
```

and

```
$ echo "FooBar" | sed -e 's/Foo(.*?)(Bar)/Hello${1}$2/'
```

I want the first to return something like: "Hello big world" and the second to return something like "Helloworld". Note: ${1} is a some sort of check... I don't know what it looks like (hence the question). if $1 is empty, I want it to say one thing, if it's not empty, I want it to say another.

Let's try a better example.
The names are:

```
"document.05.name.txt"
"document.06.txt"
```

I'm feeding them into the same regular expression:

```
$ echo $name | sed -e 's/document.([0-9]{2}).(.*?).txt/doc $1${2:+ - $2}.txt/s'
```

Again note the syntax at the end is inaccurate, because that's what I'm trying to find.
I want document 05 to be named: "doc 05 - name.txt" and document 06 to be named: "doc 06.txt" Notice the lack of a dash.

Is this something that perl regular expressions can do?

I'm looking for a one liner so I can feed this into rename. But I'm also curious.

Comment: Note sure what you mean because it looks like you missed `world` somewhere. Did you intend to put it instead of `Bar` or after the `${1}` ?

Comment: My syntax is silly, because I'm not sure what the code would look like... ${1} is placeholder code. I want to be able to type out code that would do a `if $1; return "sometext"; else return "othertext"`
I'll try to update the the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rename 's/document\.(\d\d)\.?(\w+)?(.txt)/"docs $1".($2 && " - $2").$3/e' document.*.txt
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain the detail of your answer.

Comment: for s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/e, in the PATTERN part, 3 captures are reserved, '/e' modifier at the end is to evaluate the string in the REPLACEMENT part which is the concatenation of a string "docs $1", an expression ($2 && " - $2") and another string $3.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sed` does not implement non-greedy repeats. `.*?` means "any number of characters followed by a literal <kbd>?</kbd>" (unless you specified extended regex format, in which case it just means "any number of characters", exactly like `.*`9
2. In `sed` replacements, the syntax for "substitute capture N" is `\N` (single digit only, so a maximum of 9 captures are allowed). `$1` and `${2}` are both considered just literal replacements.
3. Unless you specify `-r` (for Gnu sed; it's `-E` on BSD seds), you need to use Basic Regular Expressions, in which captures are surrounded by `\(` and `\)` instead of `(` and `)`. (Also with the `+` operator and explicit repeats; eg., `[0-9]\{2\}`.)
4. `.` always means "any character". If you want to match a <kbd>.</kbd>, use `\.`

Now, if you want to only match a non-empty sequence, you could use `.\+` (or just `.+` with `-r`), which lets you do a replacement only if the match was non-empty. But aiui, you want to do two different matches, one on empty and the other on non-empty. So you need to provide two possible substitution commands:

```
sed -r -e 's/document\.([0-9]{2})\.(.+)\.txt/document \1 - \2.txt/' \
       -e t \
       -e 's/document\.([0-9]{2})\.txt/document \1.txt/'
```

The `t` command skips to the next cycle if the preceding `s` command successfully replaced something.

Note: I wrote that out with 3 `-e` options so that it wouldn't cause right-scroll, but in practice I'd just use a single `sed` command argument with the three `sed` commands separated with semicolons.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I shouldn't have used sed, since I really meant to use 'rename'.
I keep forgetting that sed doesn't use perl...

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file|perl -pe 's/document\.([0-9]{2})\.((name\.)?txt)/"doc $1". ($3 ? " - $2":".$2")/e'
```

output

```
doc 05 - name.txt
doc 06.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain the 'x' flag? The other two answers used 'e' which I guess is needed for the logic.

Comment: @isaaclw it is not needed (when used spaces in first part of `s///` are ignored)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `perl` regex with `/e` modifier:

```
p='Foo big Bar'    
perl -pe 's/Foo(.*)Bar/my $s=$1; $s =~ s~^\s+|\s+$~~g; $s =~ s~(.+)~ $1 pretty ~; "Hello${s}world"/e' <<< "$p"
Hello big pretty world

p='Foo Bar'    
perl -pe 's/Foo(.*)Bar/my $s=$1; $s =~ s~^\s+|\s+$~~g; $s =~ s~(.+)~ $1 pretty ~; "Hello${s}world"/e' <<< "$p"
Helloworld
```